# passing an array as argument

Tags: c, arrays

I want to make a simple program that find all the prime numbers < n. I want to store the number that i found in an array. The problem is that i don't know exactly how to pass the array to function and to save the results in it. Now it doesn't save the numbers in array. Here is my code:

Edit: the expected out is to print the values using a print function i made. Now after the program leaves the nrprime funtion it deletes the answers. The problem is that the program treat that array as a local variable. How can i make to treat it as global variable and actually to really store the answers in it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

// Se citeste un numar intreg de la tastatura, sa se afiseze toate numerele prime mai mici decat n.
// calculating
int nrprime(int numar,int prime[150])
{
    int i, j, ok, index = 0;
    prime[index++] = 2;
    for (i = 3 ; i < numar ; i = i + 2)
    {
        ok = 1;
        for (j = 3 ; j <= sqrt(i) ; j = j + 2)
            if (i % j == 0)
                ok = 0;
        if (ok == 1)
        {
            printf("I:=%d", i);
            prime[index] = i;
            index++;
        }
    }
    return index;
}

// printing
void afisare(int *prime, int index)
{
    int i=0;
    printf("Numerele prime sunt:");
    for (i = 0 ; i <= index ; i++)
        printf("%d", prime[index]);
}


int main(void)
{
    int numar = 0; int prime[150];
    int index;

    printf("Introduceti un numar intreg pozitiv:\n");

    scanf("%d", &numar);
    index = nrprime(numar, prime);

    afisare(prime, index);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please explain what is your expected output and your actual output.

Comment: `for (i = 0 ; i <= index ; i++)` → `for (i = 0 ; i < index ; i++)`

Comment: @CoolGuy I think it was ok, note that `index` is passed as a parameter from a value that was read with `scanf()`, perhaps it requires a `if ((scanf("%d", &numar) != 1) || (numar > 149)) numar = 149;`?

Comment: Voting to close this as simple typo since the problem is not the parameter passing, but just a simple variable mix-up between `i` and `index` in the printing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bug in printing.

Is:

```
// printing
void afisare(int *prime, int index)
{
    int i=0;
    printf("Numerele prime sunt:");
    for (i = 0 ; i <= index ; i++)
        printf("%d", prime[index]);
}
```

Should be:

```
// printing
void afisare(int *prime, int index)
{
    int i=0;
    printf("Numerele prime sunt:");
    for (i = 0 ; i <= index ; i++)
        printf("%d", prime[i]);
        //                ^^^
}
```

Be careful not to exceed array length in for loop.

Comment: loop too long by 1 item

Comment: Not really. It depends what it is meant to do. It's not bug so far.

Comment: In case index < 150.

Comment: Based on OP code, with no array size checking, the loop with `<=` will print always an element more that the number of values returned by `nrprime`...

Comment: ...and less than numar which OP gives independently of array size. There is no error in function's afisare loop stop condition. (I would correct this anyway as well, always prefer < than <= in loop condition).

Answer (score 3):

Passing the array as argument works fine in your program, the problem is elsewhere:

In `afisare` replace

```
printf("%d", prime[index]);
```

with

```
printf("%d\n", prime[i]);
```

Comment: ahh thank you man it was so simple.  I was thinking that i pass that arguments wrong.

Answer (score 0):

your rest of the code is correct. You are making mistake while printing. Following is the correct code.

```
void afisare(int *prime, int index)
{
    int i=0;
    printf("Numerele prime sunt:");
    for (i = 0 ; i < index ; i++)
        printf("%d\n", prime[i]);
}
```